# Is time a vector in Minkowski space?

Tags: special-relativity, time, vectors, tensor-calculus, covariance

I am arguing about this topic with my school teacher in so long time, I want to  finish this debate. My teacher's opinion is "Yes, Time is vector" because four-vector has $t$ component, and mine is "No. Time is not vector" here is my counterargument:

1. proper time $\tau$ is obviously scalar, and since $t=\gamma\tau$ and $\gamma$ is scalar, $\tau$is scalar, so time $t$ is scalar.
2. if time is a vector, it should have four components, but time is not. Time is just a component of a 4-vector, not a vector itself.
3. in normal 3-dimensional space, position vector has $x,y,z$ components, but "length" is not a vector, so time is not a vector for the same reason.

And here is teacher's answer,

1. speed of light $c$ is a constant, so $\dfrac{v}{c}$ is not dimensionless number, so gamma is still vector.

Can anyone answer this problem with clear and strong reasons?

Comment: Like many arguments with teachers, it depends on your definitions. The timelike coordinate is a component of a vector, so it's a vector. But vectors are objects over scalar fields, so it's a scalar. But you could also define the object "$t$" as a timelike unit vector $t$ (For which $t^{\mu}t_{\mu}=-1$), so it's a vector. But in general relativity you can regard coordinates as scalar functions over a patch on your manifold, so it's a scalar. :P It's basically just arguing over a definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time is neither a vector nor a scalar.  It is a component of a vector.

A scalar is a quantity that does not change in value under boosts.  In Euclidean space, a scalar is a quantity that does not change under rotations, such as distance.  Time definitely has different values in different frames, so it can't be a scalar.

But a vector, as you point out, has as many components as the space in which it appears.  Four for space time and three for Euclidean space.  So time is not a vector.

The proper name is *component of a vector*.

Comment: Alternatively: yes, time is a vector, in particular it is the tangent vector to your world-line.  Or to be more precise: $t$ is the (a) parameter of your world line, and $d/dt$ is the tangent vector (up to factors of $c$).